# facebook c# api, video getting uploaded but its PUBLIC

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am able to upload video from the code below. But the video isn't PRIVATE. I need video to be PRIVATE or in other words it should be SELF.

```
FacebookMediaObject mediaObject1 = new FacebookMediaObject
{
FileName = pbmFile.fullPath,
ContentType = Path.GetExtension(filePath)
};
byte[] fileBytes1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
mediaObject1.SetValue(fileBytes1);
IDictionary<string, object> upload1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
upload1.Add("image", mediaObject1);

staticGlobalConst.fbClient1.Post("/me/videos", upload1, staticGlobalConst.del1Video) as JsonObject
```

When I add the code below it throws exception

I tried adding parameter

```
upload1.Add("privacy", "SELF");
```

How can I upload a private video?

Thanks
Sujit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding below parameter

```
upload1.Add("privacy", "{\"value\":\"SELF\"}");
```

Answer (score 0):

that is depends on what was your choice for " `Visibility of app and posts:` " option when the first time you authenticated with the app.

you can change it to : **`Public,Friends,Only Me`** , from your `Account Settings>Apps` and choose your application and change it .

Comment: Thanks Eslam. I can't use your solution, as I can't ask the user to change his/ her settings. I solved it by adding below parameter

      upload1.Add("privacy", "{\"value\":\"SELF\"}");